# how can I check the existence of a word 'worm' in a data set contains different names:

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataset which has 1854 rows and 106 columns , in the third column of it there are values like "Worm.Win32.Zwr.c" (and other type of malware names) ,I want to check if there is a word like `'worm'` in any rows then insert 1 in target column of the same row

```
for rows in malware_data:
    if ('worm' in malware_data[3]):
        malware_data.loc[rows]['target']=1

    else:
        malware_data.loc[rows]['target']=0
```

Comment: Does your target column have values as lists? you are saying to insert

Answer (score 1):

you can do this in several ways:

1) by creating a bool mask to filter what rows contain your word 'worm':

```
mask = df.str.lower().str.contains('worm')

df.loc[mask, third_column].target = 1
df.loc[~mask, third_column].target = 0
```

insetad of `df.str.lower().str.contains('worm')` you can use `df.str.contains('(?i)worm')`

if you do not know the name of your third column you could use:

```
third_column = df.columns[2]
```

2) by applying a function along your third column of the DataFrame as @ArunPrabhath  suggested:

```
df.target = df[third_column].apply(lamda x: int('worm' in x.lower()))
```

Answer (score 0):

malware_data['target'] = malware_data[3].apply(lamda row: 1 if ('worm' in row) else 0)